# C++ Code is not calculating the time difference but it is returning -0

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>/* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, difftime, time, mktime */

using namespace std;

//Code for calculating time date difference
int main ()
{
  time_t now;
  struct tm newyear1, newyear2;
  double seconds;

  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */

  newyear1 = *localtime(&now);

  newyear1.tm_hour = 10; newyear1.tm_min = 30;
  newyear1.tm_mon = 0;  newyear1.tm_mday = 1;newyear1.tm_year = 2021;
  newyear2 = *localtime(&now);

  newyear2.tm_hour = 23; newyear2.tm_min = 10;
  newyear2.tm_mon = 0;  newyear2.tm_mday = 1;newyear2.tm_year = 2021;

  seconds = difftime(mktime(&newyear2),mktime(&newyear1))/3600.0;

  cout<<seconds<<" hours since new year in the current timezone.";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is technically `c++`, but the question is about using the C standard library. I would suggest you reformat the question as C code and use the `c` tag. You'll have a better shot at getting a solid and quick answer.

Comment: Can you help me rewriting or correcting that code?

Comment: Does not return 0 for me - live - https://godbolt.org/z/P5969so4c are you sure you are not looking at the _"...Program returned: 0..."_ message which is from `return 0;` are the end of `main` ?

Comment: `2021` in `tm_year` means `3921` which is presumably out of the range of representable values for `time_t` on your platform so `mktime` returns `-1`

Comment: But I want my code to be in C++

Comment: @SheheryarRamzan Whatever answer you get will be also true in C++. But since you are using a standard C library:`<time.h>` instead of the standard C++ library: `<chrono>`, It makes more sense to target the question at C experts.

Comment: On online compiler it is working fine but gives issues when I run it on my own compiler

Comment: Even with <chrono> it isn't working fine

Comment: presumably you are using windows which limits `mktime` to the year `3000`, the online compilers probably are using linux which allows larger values